# Adding a class into a frame and fixing button

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, graphics

Ok so i made this program that moves the picture to the end and when you click on a button, it draws a line from the picture to this point. I am able to make the whole button thing, however, I suck at layouts and stuff. So when i run my program, it opens 2 java programs, one where the animation is happening and one for button.. I dont want that.. I want the button to be on the same java program as the animation. Also, I am trying to set the background color but it isn't working.. I am sure it has to do with frames or something.. idk. Please help. Here is my class for main method:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class example extends JFrame implements Runnable, ActionListener{
    private int W=1000;
    private int H=1500;
    private Thread thread;
    private int c=1;
    int q=0;
    Image image= new ImageIcon("Pictures/car.png").getImage();
    private move greenCar;
    public example(){
        setBounds(100,100,W,H);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        thread= new Thread(this);
        greenCar=new move(image,30,70,98,40);
        thread.start();

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        //draws the image on the screen
        g.drawImage(greenCar.getImg(), greenCar.getX(), greenCar.getY(), this);
        //c becomes 2 if the image has reached x=699 and if the button is pressed, q becomes greater than 0
        if(c==2 &&q>0)
        {
            //and when that happens, a line gets created from stretching from the picture to a point
            g.drawLine(greenCar.getX(), greenCar.getY(), 10, 20);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //new example();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                new example().createGui();
            }
        });


    }
    protected void createGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button");
        frame.setSize(30, 30);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Profile");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40);
        panel.add(button1, c);
        button1.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void run() {
        while(true)
        {
            //starting the animation

            greenCar.animate();
            repaint();
            //if the picture is above 698, set c as 2
            if(greenCar.getX()>698)
            {
                c=2;
            }
            try{
                thread.sleep(13);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
            }
            }
            }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //q, which was initially 0, gets incremented 
        q++;

    }
}
```

and for the animation of image:

```
import java.awt.Image;
public class move {
    private Image img;
    private int x,y,width,height;
    public move(Image img, int x,int  y, int width, int height){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
        this.img=img;
    }

    public Image getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
    public void animate(){
        if(getX()<700)
        setX(getX()+1);
        if(getX()>700) 
            x=701;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please ask one specific focused question per post. Why do you want `move` to be in the `JFrame` class ? (BTW to follow java naming conventions the class name should be `Move`).

Comment: Hi, Well, I feel as maybe thats how i can set its background to a different color? I dont know. But most importantly, i want the button to be on the same program as the animation

Comment: @c0der but idk how to do that :/

Comment: "Why do you want 'move` to be in the `JFrame` class ? " (or visa versa)

Comment: @c0der So that perhaps i can be able to change its background color.. cos right now when i try to do that it doesn't work

Comment: @c0der actually i figured out the problem :) thank u so much btw :)

Comment: BTW consider using `boolean` for  `c` and `q`